# Configure httpd.conf for SVN

Tags: centos, svn, centos6.4

I need to configure svn on centos 6.4 (final). I installed svn 1.6 and done the initial configuration but while accessing the repository via url i am getting a list of svn conf files/folders instead of prompting for the authentication. ([Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/enog22u82s5g05s/kt_Repo.png))

Comment: Do you really need subversion 1.8?

Comment: Of course not. I only want to install svn on server. i tried with 1.6, but its also not working.

Comment: So what happened when you did `yum install subversion`?

Comment: Actually its installed successfully, but when i trying to access the svn url its showing some file/folders instead of prompting for username/password. Like this (https://www.dropbox.com/s/enog22u82s5g05s/kt_Repo.png) . I don't know the actual cause of this issue. So am trying with the higher versions.? Could you please identify the issue..?

Comment: That problem has nothing to do with the _version_ of subversion that you're using. If you want to solve it, you should ask directly about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i got it working :) 
I Done the following things

Added

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

in **httpd.conf**

Copied `mod_dav_svn.so` `and mod_authz_svn.so` from /usr/lib64/httpd/modules to /etc/httpd/modules

```
cp /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so /etc/httpd/modules/
cp /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_svn.so /etc/httpd/modules/
```

Added the following in **httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost myipaddress:80>
ServerName myipaddress
DocumentRoot /var/www

<Directory /var/www>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Location /svn/TestRepo>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /var/www/svn/TestRepo
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "My project"
  SVNPathAuthz on
  AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth.htpasswd
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /svn/authz.conf
  Order deny,allow
  Require valid-user
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks *ALex_hha* for helping me to find out the actual cause of the issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to install directly from [WanDisco](http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/svn-1.8/RPMS/x86_64/) repositories without needing to upgrade sqlite

You must enable dav in the vhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName svn.example.net
DocumentRoot /vhosts/svn.example.net

<Directory /vhosts/svn.example.net>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "SVN Repository. Authorization required."
    AuthUserFile /etc/svn/svn_users
    Require valid-user
</Location>

<Location /Test>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /svn/Test
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svn/test.conf
    SVNReposName "Test SVN Repository"
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

After that create repo

```
# svnadmin create /svn/Test
# chown -R apache:apache /svn/Test
```

Comment: I already tried with `WanDisco`. I am getting a list of files and folders while accessing the repository via url instead of prompting for the svn username/password. check this(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/ih7LgqCM0ZiCJ91Bpy_uwMCEd9oL8E4GLculMib-DtpKB4QHj2YRdaRlX_mEUxdD3fBJhM3cMQ)

Comment: It's not related to the sqlite upgrading. The link is not accessible. Add config of vhost to your question

Comment: Yeah its not related with `sqlite`. it occured when i tried to install svn using WanDisco, thats why i unistalled `WanDisco` and trying to install svn using subversion-1.8.1.tar.gz and that needs sqlite upgrade. Sorry for the above image link. Can you check this (https://www.dropbox.com/s/enog22u82s5g05s/kt_Repo.png)

Comment: Install svn from WanDisco and show vhost config

Comment: I just installed svn from WanDisco and here is my vhost config : https://www.dropbox.com/s/93mdyg6ossp4fwy/Screen%20Shot%202013-08-27%20at%207.44.44%20PM.png

Comment: I changed the vhost config as above and added `LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so` in httpd.conf. Now i am getting this error while restarting httpd `Cannot load /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_dav_svn.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: mod_authz_svn.so and mod_dav_svn.so should be located in the /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/

Comment: mod_authz_svn.so and mod_dav.so is already there in /usr/lib64/httpd/modules